# How to detect if the value entered in HTML CSS input is a number

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a code like this:

```
Age: <input type="text" id="age">
```

And JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        let age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        if (age) // is number?
    }
</script>
```

I want the input to give an error if the value entered is a letter, I will only accept numbers. How can I tell if the entered value is not a number?

Comment: Why not use an input type number, `<input type="number"/>`. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using/depending on CSS you can apply the style to HTML elements using plain JavaScript as follows.

```js
        function validateForm() {
            let age = document.getElementById("age").value;             
            if (!isNaN(age)) {
               document.getElementById("age").style.borderColor="red";
            }
        }
```

```html
   Age: <input type="text" onchange ="validateForm()" id="age">
```